# Why does this Array lose its data outside $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, arrays, instagram

I'm sending a request to Instagram to get followers IDs and everything goes OK, until I want to use the array outside of `$.getJSON` method. The following is the relevant part of code:

```
var allFollowings = [];
 $.getJSON("https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/follows?access_token="+$.urlParam('access_token')+"&count="+followingsCount+"&callback=?", function(json) {


   for(var i = 0; i < json.data.length; i++) {
        console.log(json.data[i].id); // this is not empty
        allFollowings[i] = json.data[i].id;
   }
   console.log(allFollowings); // this is also not empty
});
console.log(allFollowings); // this one is empty!!!
```

Obviously I'm doing something wrong and it's the first time I've come across this problem. But what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It actually does not lose its data. What happens is that your `$.getJSON` callback function is being invoked asynchronously after your last `console.log(allFollowings);` call.

Comment: While I completely agree with you and your assessment of javascript's personality, saying that it's not a synchronous language is a bit of an overstatement. It's not so much the language as the `.getJSON` function in this example for instance ;)

Comment: How can I use this in as a parameter in another function after $.getJSON? Because right now it's empty in the function?

Comment: Just call your other function passing `allFollwings` as parameter inside the getJSON callback.

Comment: Thanks for the observation Michael, I think now it's correct. :)

Comment: Yeah, even more cautious than mine, I think I'll upvote it ;)

Answer (score 0):

The `console.log` at the end of your script is executed *before* the `getJSON` invokes the callback. It's asynchronous nature of javascript.